# How to set an option selected if the item of an array is equal to the value of the option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a select list (*`let's name it fraction select list`*) like this which appends by jQuery:

```
$("#optionPanel").append('<div class="form-group col-md-3"><select id="fraction" class="form-control" width="100%" id="navigationMethod"><option value="0.0" selected="">Nothing</option><option value="1.0">100%</option><option value="0.9">90%</option><option value="0.8333333">83.33333%</option><</select>');
```

when I click on a button, I can get the value of the select list and set it inside a variable.

```
var selectedOption : '';

$('#submitBtn').on('click',function(){
   selectedOption = $('#fraction').val()
});
```

Now I have an edit button too, I want to do something when I clicked on the edit button, the `fraction selectlist's value be as the same as the selectedOption's variable's value and the option be selected.

As I said, my selectlist is being generated by jQuery, it's not a simple HTML selectlist so we can use *selected* attribute easily.

I would appreciate it if you help me with that.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the existing code. Also, what error did you get?

Comment: I don't know how to do so I don't have code, I searched but I could't see my issue anywhere @HassanImam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `selectedOption` on click of edit button which will change the selected value in `select`.

```js
$("#optionPanel").append('<div class="form-group col-md-3"><select id="fraction" class="form-control" width="100%" id="navigationMethod"><option value="0.0" selected="">Nothing</option><option value="1.0">100%</option><option value="0.9">90%</option><option value="0.8333333">83.33333%</option><</select>');

let selectedOption = "0.9";

$('#editBtn').on('click', function () {
  $("#optionPanel select").val(selectedOption);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='optionPanel'></div>
<button id="editBtn"> EDIT</button>
```